# Is using a password from frontend code a security risk if you don't store it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, frontend, amazon-redshift

Just want to verify that it's okay to make a request to some backend service which will provide credentials, keep the credentials in a variable in the code and then pass that variable to another service to authenticate. I know you can't store it in the browser or in the code itself but is there any issue in dynamically generating it to store in a variable to be used for a request? Is it safer to do that in the backend instead or does it not make a difference?

If the context matters- the goal is to connect to a redshift database without having to make any changes to the backend code- only updating the frontend code. The password can be retrieved from the backend but the code to connect to and interact with redshift must be done on the frontend.

Comment: Keep your credentials in the AWS Secrets Manager, it's made for this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html

Comment: If I retrieve the credentials from secrets manager then it's fine to store that in a variable in the frontend during runtime? Or should all of that be handled on the backend. Just want to double-check that there's no issue since I'm not very familiar with this.

Comment: There are many articles about this, see for example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html

Comment: It seems like none of those options are related to the frontend. The first 2 require lambda or ec2. The rest require credentials stored in files or environment variables which I think would be unavailable from the frontend. And I'm just wondering about storing it in a variable once I get it from the backend- the way it's handled in the backend would be unrelated to what I'm concerned about.

Comment: If you send out a password to any arbitrary client, it's not a secret password any more - it's public data. Yes, this is absolutely insecure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's never safe or secure to use secrets in this manner.

Everything you send to the client is public, no exceptions.  Even if you don't store the secret as a variable, it can still be viewed, for example, in the memory profiler and in the network tab of devtools.

Another reason this is unsafe is due to native prototype pollution and modifications.  Take me for instance.  I have a browser extension I coded that replaces the fetch and XMLHttpRequest functions in the context of the page with "passthrough recording" functions.  The appear the same to the outside, even emulating the toString "native code" aspect.  However, what they actually do is record everything concerning the request and response while forwarding the data as if they weren't there.  While I use this for logging unsafe traffic and debugging, it wouldn't be difficult to turn it into a data scraper for malicious purposes.

The best alternative, if modifying the existing backend code isn't an option.  Is to create an entirely new backend service that handles the connection and data streams.  Because I promise you, if you send secrets to the client, someone like me, with just a little bit more bad intent will make you seriously regret it.

Comment: Thanks. And just to confirm, even if you're using HTTPS, the response will show up in in the network tab in plaintext, right?

Comment: Yes, SSL is terminated at the client, so you can see everything in the network tab, HTTP and HTTPS both.  There are several companies that attempt to send obfuscated secrets and use a slim backend service to authenticate.  But realistically it will only add a minor inconvenience for someone who really wants in and has a lot of time on their hands.

So far (8 years or so of serious experience), I have not found a way to securely send a secret to the client side for authentication.